# Get specific value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this json.  I only care about the uniqueIDs.

How can I get ONLY the uniqueID values delivered back to me as a comma separated list, ie, 11111, 22222?  (I need to create my own array.)  I can't edit the json below - I am just trying to parse the value I care about out of it....

```
{
        products: [{
            type: "Unique",
            name: "Joe",
            description: "Joes Description",
            uniqueID: "11111"
        }, {
            type: "Unique",
            name: "Jane",
            description: "Janes Description",
            uniqueID: "22222"
        }]
}
```

Thought it would be this easy but its not...

```
$data['uniqueID'][0]
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is a JSON file and you've included this from the HTML file, yes?

Comment: This is not json. It's only a JavaScript object.

Comment: correct - this is a json file that I am calling in the html

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py21wco2/10/). The json is printed in console, as it would be returned from the server, using `JSON.stringify`, that converts a JavaScript value ( the object in my case for creating a `JSON`)  to a `JSON string`.

Comment: updated - products was not inside metadata :(

Comment: Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py21wco2/14/), not really a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use map function:

```
var foo = {
  metadata: {
    products: [{
      type: "Unique",
      name: "Joe",
      description: "Joes Description",
      uniqueID: "11111"
    } {
      type: "Unique",
      name: "Jane",
      description: "Janes Description",
      uniqueID: "22222"
    }]
  }
}
var ids = foo.metadata.products.map(x => x.uniqueID);
```

And if you are not familiar with arrow function:

```
var ids = foo.metadata.products.map(function(x){
    return x.uniqueID;
});
```

Comment: says metadata not defined :(

Comment: What is your main variable name? Can you put the full code?

Comment: There is no variable... the file I am referencing is only the json and begins with  { metadata....

Answer (score 0):

### The Underscore Way

You can use underscore js  `_.pluck()`  or  `_.map()`  function.

```js
var data = {
  metadata: {
    products: [{
      type: "Unique",
      name: "Joe",
      description: "Joes Description",
      uniqueID: "11111"
    },
    {
      type: "Unique",
      name: "Jane",
      description: "Janes Description",
      uniqueID: "22222"
    }]
  }
};


//Use plunk method
var uniqueIDArr = _.pluck(data.metadata.products, 'uniqueID'); 

console.log(uniqueIDArr);
//=> ["11111", "22222"]

//Use map function
var uniqueIDArr = _.map(data.metadata.products, function(obj) {
  return obj.uniqueID;
}); 
console.log(uniqueIDArr);
//=> ["11111", "22222"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/underscorejs/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and chain a [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the `uniqueIDsString` in a single line:

```js
var obj = {metadata: {products: [{type: "Unique",name: "Joe",description: "Joes Description",uniqueID: "11111"}, {type: "Unique",name: "Jane",description: "Janes Description",uniqueID: "22222"}]}},
    uniqueIDsString = obj
        .metadata
        .products
        .map(function(product) {
            return product.uniqueID;
        })
        .join(', ');

console.log(uniqueIDsString);
```